# Adding extension property to Azure ActiveDirectory user via Power Shell

Tags: powershell, azure, active-directory

I am logged in into Azure AD that I created for test. I am trying to add extension property to user:

I first added extension type to my application:
Command:

```
New-AzureADApplicationExtensionProperty -ObjectID 513aba62-4610-44ef-8be2-5a5e99a5e6bd -DataType "string" -Name "organisationId"
```

Result:

```
extension_d939d34ab3f34f5dbb6e4e5c35e5787a_organisationId
```

ObjectId of application: 513aba62-4610-44ef-8be2-5a5e99a5e6bd

Then I retrieved the id of extension propert:
Command:

```
Get-AzureADApplicationExtensionProperty -ObjectId 513aba62-4610-44ef-8be2-5a5e99a5e6bd
```

Now I am trying to add this extension to my first user in active directory:

```
$User = Get-AzureADUser -Top 1
Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $User.ObjectId -ExtensionName extension_d939d34ab3f34f5dbb6e4e5c35e5787a_organisationId -ExtensionValue "12345"
```

Error:

```
Set-AzureADUserExtension : Error occurred while executing SetUser 
Code: Request_BadRequest Message: The following extension properties
are not available for the given resource:
extension_d939d34ab3f34f5dbb6e4e5c35e5787a_organisationId. RequestId:
2cbeff0f-5b91-478a-8c64-586a4d23e4c5 DateTimeStamp: Wed, 14 Jun 2017
13:49:02 GMT HttpStatusCode: BadRequest HttpStatusDescription: Bad
Request HttpResponseStatus: Completed At line:2 char:1
+ Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $User.ObjectId -ExtensionName exte ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-AzureADUserExtension], ApiException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Graph.PowerShell.Custom.SetAzureADUserExtension
```

I am using these docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureaduserextension?view=azureadps-2.0

Comment: did you want long enough for it to propagate? like 10-15 minutes?

Comment: i tried now after 2 hours, still same error

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this same issue.
For me creating an AzureAD Service Principal for the application seemed to solve the problem.

```
# CREATE A NEW APP AND SERVICE PRINCIPAL
$MyApp = (New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "YourNewAppName" -IdentifierUris "https://dummy").ObjectId 
New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId (Get-AzureADApplication -SearchString "YourNewAppName").AppId 

# CREATE A NEW EXTENSION PROPERTY IN THE APP
New-AzureADApplicationExtensionProperty -ObjectId $MyApp -Name "YourPropertyName" -DataType "String" -TargetObjects "User" 

# ADD THE NEW EXTENSION PROPERTY WITH A VALUE TO A USER
$aadUser = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId youruser@yourdomain.com
Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $aadUser.ObjectId -ExtensionName "yourExtensionNameReturnedAbove" -ExtensionValue "YourPropertyValue"
```

See: [MS PowerShell AzureAD Extension Attributes Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/using-extension-attributes-sample?view=azureadps-2.0)

Answer (score 0):

For now, we can't use PowerShell to add extension property to Azure AD users.
`New-AzureADApplicationExtensionProperty` create the extension property is not for users, we can use PowerShell command `Get-AzureADUser` to check it.

```
PS C:\Users\v-jianye> $d = get-azureaduser -ObjectId 65120ec5-3be1-4365-9d1c-b190414a830f
PS C:\Users\v-jianye> $d.ExtensionProperty

Key                         Value
---                         -----
odata.metadata              https://graph.windows.net/5b47c786-9ca0-4347-9ec8-06590cad075f/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User/@Element
odata.type                  Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User
deletionTimestamp
facsimileTelephoneNumber
onPremisesDistinguishedName

PS C:\Users\v-jianye> $c = get-azureaduser -ObjectId 9821a55c-c4c1-46dd-8471-5f99ee8e7c0d
PS C:\Users\v-jianye> $c.ExtensionProperty

Key                                                               Value
---                                                               -----
odata.metadata                                                    https://graph.windows.net/5b47c786-9ca0-4347-9ec8-06590cad075f/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User/@Element
odata.type                                                        Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User
deletionTimestamp
facsimileTelephoneNumber
onPremisesDistinguishedName
extension_70e35fde0e05483aa8ace7c8c6d3fb93_whenCreated@odata.type Edm.DateTime
extension_70e35fde0e05483aa8ace7c8c6d3fb93_whenCreated            12/6/2016 4:06:34 AM
```

Microsoft provides two ways to add custom data to resources using extensions, they are **open extensions** and **schema extensions**.
More details about create open extension, please refer to this [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/opentypeextension_post_opentypeextension#request-body).